# IP Address from a mobile device's request

Tags: android, ios, web-services, mobile, asp.net-web-api

If a mobile app (not a mobile browser) is making a request to a web service:

1. How do I find the IP address (Is it in the `Request` object?)
2. If the mobile device is using the mobile network (ex: Verizon), is the IP address the IP address from the provider?
3. If the mobile device is using the Wifi, is the IP address that of the wireless router?
4. Also, what happens if i make device A (say on Tmobile) a wifi hotspot and connect device B (on Verizon) and make a request. What IP address is sent in the `Request` object?

Thanks

Comment: You did not define which mobile you are talking about ? it dependes on type of OS the mobile is using..So mentioned is it andriod,windows or ios etc

Comment: @Garry - I care about Android and IOS for now. Thanks for the question

Comment: Are you trying to figure out what the Client IP is on the server? Are you using Web API selfhosted or webhosted?

Comment: @YoussefMoussaoui Web API web hosted. I am trying to figure out the IP address of the mobile device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Try this:

```
string ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Note: this won't work in self-host, only in web-host.

2) The IP address the server sees will be associated with the mobile network. The IP address can change over time too as the phone moves and reconnects to the network.

3) Yes, the IP address the server sees will be the IP address of the router.

4) The IP address will be associated with the mobile network again. The IP address the server gets will be the same IP address as the server sees for the phone with the wifi hotspot. The phone effectively becomes a router.

Comment: Any thoughts on my other questions (2), (3), (4) ?

Answer (score 0):

It's more complicated than that -- carriers now have "on the fly NAT".   Your connection may be stable as far as your device is concerned, with a known address, but the service in question might see different IP addresses/port combinations, even IPv4 or IPv6 combinations, request by request if the carrier chooses to do so.  Given the shortage of IPv4 addresses, the need to apply content filters (legal requirements), CALEA, etc. you rarely get a "direct connect" to the Internet.